# Excel copy cell upon another cell that is different then increment and continue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to copy a bunch of IDs on the same column but in one shot, the incrementation being automatic

Here an example : 
[image]

In this case, I want 1077 to be copied in all cells until it reach 1078, then 1078 should be copied until 1079 and etc..

Known the numbers (in green) are already written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new column B,in B1 write:

`=A1`

In B2 write:

`=IF(A2="",B1,A2)`

and drag it down
When finish you can select all B copy and Paste Special Values in a new column and delete the old columns (A and B)

Comment: Perfect, Working ! Thanx.